# angularjs removing/escaping apostrophe (') from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `angularjs` function that will add a product to the array, but I'm having a problem when the description of the product has a apostrophe (') in it, how can I escape/remove that

Code:

```
$scope.addProductToList = function(product) {
    product = product.replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\t/g, "\\t");
}
```

Error:

```
Syntax Error: Token 's' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 762
```

Error because of the `'` in the product description.

Answer (score -1):

A clean way to scape `'` in this scenario could be wrapping your outter string with `"` instead of `'`.
For example: `"It's my birthday"`